Is there a way to do "dynamic indexing" for commodities in PowerBI?
I am currently trying to develop a commodities dashboard. I have indexed all of the datasets I'm tracking in this dashboard to June 2018 = 100 and included a slicer so I can select the start and end dates I want to look at the data over.
However, I am wondering if it is possible to alter this slicer so that the selected start date is automatically set at 100, and the rest of the dataset is calculated to determine the index from that point.
Let me know if I can provide clarification!
Picture of dashboard so far
I have followed several online tutorials but I haven't gotten the result I was hoping for as I am unfamiliar with DAX and none of the formulas seemed to work for me. I also don't think the tutorials were exactly what I was looking for.
